# Zend Framework v. 1.12 don't return array from database without ->limit()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

In Zend Framework v. 1.12 I have to return an array of results from database, if I use `->limit()` it works if limit is lower than 10.000, otherwise if I don't use LIMIT or LIMIT is greater than 10.000, it doesn't work.

```
//SELECT * FROM customers -> not works
//SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 10000-> works

//here's the code
$query = $this->db->select();
$query->from(array('c'=>'customers'));

$query->limit(50); 
$stmt = $this->db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
Zend_Debug::dump($result);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Seems like server limit. Zend does not have limits on number of rows taken from DB.

Comment: The query works on phpmyamin with or without LIMIT

Comment: There were any thing to do on Server side on mysql configuration to make it works?